# a MWE of LaTeX3 package

Tags: xetex, latex3

How do I write a XeTeX program from [this package](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) which just prints the result of this command

```
\use_i_ii:nnn { abc } { { def } } { ghi }
```

when called **as a function** `$\foo{ abc } { { def } } { ghi }$`
to an output page like this:

```
$abc{def}$
```

What I need is a MWE with all the stuff around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn
```

...
I'm currently unable to create a MWE. IN particular, I'm unable to guess this line:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn
```

with variations of `protected:Npn`

**YOUR COMMENT GIVES THIS ERROR YET AFTER UPGRADING MIKTEX:**

```
    Command Line:   D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje31.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(ideje31.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW2\tex/latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW2\tex/latex\base\size10.clo))
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \ExplSyntaxOn 
                              
l.3 \ExplSyntaxOn
                   \cs_new_protected:Npn
? 

! Emergency stop.
<recently read> \ExplSyntaxOn 
                              
l.3 \ExplSyntaxOn
                   \cs_new_protected:Npn
No pages of output.

_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\cs_new_protected:Npn\mycommand #1#2#3{
\use_i_ii:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mycommand{ abc } { { def } } { ghi }
\end{document}`?

Comment: @Noone Please see the **EDIT**.

Comment: Your LaTeX is too old.

Comment: @TeXnician Shall I upgrade MikTeX ?

Comment: Or add `\usepackage{expl3}` before the syntax on. But when considering to work with expl3, most likely yes.

Comment: @TeXnician Please See my **EDIT2** .

Comment: @TeXnician I have upgraded MikTeX but LaTeX seems to be still old. How do I upgrade it ?

Comment: Maybe you should install `expl3` manually from MikTeX and then try with `\usepackage{expl3}`

Comment: @Noone having used `\usepackage{expl3} ` your code works. But I would like to follow this comment: `But when considering to work with expl3, most likely yes`.